# Input field blank even with value when <input name="name">

Tags: html, firefox

I have the following form text input like this:

```
<input name="name" type="text" value="test" id="name">
```

It will not show the value, if I change the name attribute to something else it works. It is hardcoded and there are no javascripts interacting with it.

**Update:** It works fine in Internet Explorer and Google Chrome, won't work in Firefox.

**Update 2:** I was able to replicate the problem.

For example, in my localhost I access /blog/login, the input name shows the value test, which is hardcoded, if I delete the value and reload, without submiting anything, then input name will be blank as long as I reload. If I navigate again to /blog/login, the hardcoded value will be show again.

This behavior doesn't happens in IE and Chrome.

I apologize if this was a silly question, but this is really strange, I guess.

Comment: works fine for me here's the html: `<html><input name="name" type="text" value="test" id="name"/></html>`

Comment: I just tested this in Firefox at http://jsbin.com . It is working fine. Can you clarify what is wrong?

Comment: Take a look at the most basic case in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3mWvE/ And then see what you need to add in order to reproduce the problem that you're seeing.

Comment: It is working now in Firefox, without modifying anything. The only thing I previously did was shift+delete the auto-filled value, yet this is strange as hell. But I can already see this is coming back to haunt me.

Answer (score 0):

Browsers add names and ids of form controls as properties to the FORM. This results in the properties of the form being replaced.

Browsers also may add names and id's of other elements as properties to document, and sometimes to the global object (or an object above the global object in scope). This non-standard behavior can result in replacement of properties on other objects. The problems it causes are discussed in detail.

A problem occurs when a form control's name conflicts with the a property name of the FORM object.

**For example:**

Simple Unsafe Name Example

```
<form action="">
  <input type="text" name="name">
  <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

**Result**

The element with `name="name"` replaces the value of the FORM's name property. A similar type of conflict happens with the FORM's submit method and the element with `name="submit`'. Which will win?

In most cases, the form control wins and the FORM's property is replaced to have the value of the form control, or, if more than one form control has that name, the FORM's property is replaced with a NodeList containing those form controls.

However, in some cases, the FORM's property is not replaced to have the value of the form control with the same name. The examples in this page show that the result depends on the browser, the property, and how the control is added.

http://jibbering.com/faq/names/

Comment: This is interesting, but how does it explain the phenomenon described in the question? The `form` tag was not disclosed, but even if it has a `name` attribute, the `input` element name would override it, not vice versa (at least on Firefox).